# Can I use "fix" instead of "cure"?

Tags: word-usage

Are these expressions common and appropriate?

> I have to fix my cold.
>
> This medicine can fix your hay fever.

Comment: One of the two options in the following would be more common and appropriate: "I have to get {over / rid of [CHOOSE ONE]} my cold".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would label those sentences as an informal use of the word *fix*.

A native speaker might use the word *fix* when talking about an illness or condition, but I think it would be considered a rather informal (if not humorous) use of the word.  *Fix* is usually applied to something more mechanical, such as an engine, or abstract, like a problem.

Conversationally, someone might say:

> I need to get over my cold.

A more formal word might be *remedy*:

> This medicine can *remedy* your hay fever.

although I think *remedy* is more likely to be seen as a noun:

> This medicine would be the best remedy for your hay fever.

Off the top of my head, the verb I'd probably recommend for most day-to-day use would be *treat*:

> I have to **treat** my cold. This medicine can **treat** your hay fever.

One of the key differences between *treat* and *fix* (or *cure*) is that, with treatment, there's not necessarily a guarantee that the condition will be ultimately remedied – you can *treat* a cold unsuccessfully, and still have the symptoms linger.

Comment: "I have to *cure* my cold" sounds strange because there is no cure for the common cold.  I would talk about *getting better*, personally.